# How to get a motorcycle to a skills test

Tags: motor-vehicle, north-carolina

I have a motorcycle skills test at a North Carolina DMV to hopefully pass the skills portion of the [requirements](https://www.ncdot.gov/dmv/license-id/driver-licenses/motorcycle/Pages/default.aspx). I currently have a valid car drivers license. The motorcycle in question has a legal title and insurance required in NC.

Let's say given that

- I don't have a vehicle that can transport the motorcycle
- I don't have a friend with a motorcycle license who can transport it for me

I'm wondering how exactly I'm expected to get the motorcycle to the DMV for my skills test. I am a competent rider and would feel comfortable transporting myself to and from the DMV (mostly backroads).

Driving a motorcycle without a license is illegal. However without transportation resources, I'm wondering what's expected. Even if I take an MSF class (which I certainly will in addition to the DMV test)..I still have to actually get my bike to-and-from the course.

So, my option (other than somehow obtaining a vehicle to transport it) is to ride without a license to the DMV. While the DMV might not care/notice how I've gotten the motorcycle there, obviously getting pulled over would be bad and I'd likely fully be liable for any accidents. This would be doubly awkward in the event I fail the skills test, and clearly get on my motorcycle and drive home.

In this case, what is the "correct" way to handle this situation, and how detrimental would getting pulled over / ticketed be to obtaining a motorcycle license in the future?

Comment: BTW, most MSF courses provide motorcycles, you can bring your own but they don't encourage it.

Comment: @RonBeyer In my area the MSF class is taught through a community college and requirements state "Students will need to furnish a street-legal, properly licensed and insured motorcycle of any size". However it also states "Students must possess a valid motorcycle learner’s permit or Motorcycle Endorsement before enrolling" so it's sort of a non-issue as you already have to have some skills in place before taking the class.

Comment: @rob In the two states I've taken it, they've supplied one... Guess it depends on the provider, the private orgs I've done them through all supply old 250's.

Comment: Does MSF mean Motorcycle Safety Foundation?

Comment: The DMV might actually care. I don’t see them calling the cops to ticket you but they might refuse to give you the test if you don’t have a valid learners permit. I speak from experience.

Comment: @Laurel MSF = Motorcycle Safety Foundation https://msf-usa.org

Comment: @ToddWilcox You are correct, you must get  your motorcycle to the skills testing site legally.  If you trailer it or have a driver with a motorcycle endorsement ride it there, you'll be allowed to take the test provided you meet all their other requirements.  If you ride it there without a valid learners permit you will not be allowed to take the skills test.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can ride the bike there using your [Learner's permit](https://codes.findlaw.com/nc/chapter-20-motor-vehicles/nc-gen-st-sect-20-7.html), for which you don't have to pass a skills test - just the vision, road sign and knowledge tests. Learner's permits are valid for 12 months and you aren't permitted to carry passengers.

Comment: Based on what rob is saying in the comments, this is the best answer. The Learner permit is not that hard to get apparently.

Answer (score 5):

Good news for you. The NC MSF has a [web site](https://ncmsep.org/courses/brc/) with just the answer you require.

> Upon successful completion of the BRC, you will be issued a skills
> waiver card for the NCDMV. This means the DMV **will not require you to**
> **take their motorcycle riding test**. You will still be required to visit
> your local DMV office and take their written exam before being issued
> a motorcycle endorsement.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that the NC MSF advanced course waves the skills requirement. This isn't really related to that as the question is specifically the NC DMV Motorcycle skills test.

Comment: The bold section indicates that the DMV would not require you to take that skills test. In FL, the DMV accepted my wife's certificate and issued the endorsement without involving any vehicle related testing.

Comment: That's correct. If you take the MSF course you are not required to take a skills test at the DMV. However an MSF course is not required to obtain a provisional motorcycle license. You can either take an MSF course OR a skills test at the DMV but one is required. This question is about the skills test at the DMV.

Comment: Florida now requires the MSF course, which explains part of the confusion I've created with the answer. The other answers, regarding the learner's permit are certainly valid.

Answer (score 3):

Technically you need to get a learner's permit first, then somebody can supervise your trip to the DMV.

I don't see anything saying you need to holds it for any period of time. So your options are to have somebody with a valid license transport it there for you, or get a learner's permit and be supervised on your trip there.

Comment: Thank you- this is certainly it. I misinterpreted the learners permit "motorcycle knowledge test" for the "motorcycle skills test" and that was the cause of my confusion. Thank you.

Comment: Actually on retrospect- this doesn't appear true. A motorcycle endorsement does not appear to require a learners permit based on the requirements.

Comment: No, that's not what I intended, you don't need a learner's permit, you need one to drive your motorcycle to the test of nobody else is available to drive it for you. You could also haul it or walk it there...

Comment: I think that clarification would fit well as part of the first sentence of the answer -- "Technically, to be able to ride your motorcycle to the license test, you need to get a learner's permit . . . "